# Using multiple repositories in maven cause download failure

Tags: maven, maven-2, artifactory

I have som trouble when using multiple repositories in maven. Ass additinal information we use artifactory as local repository.

I have the following maven settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<servers>
    <server>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
    <server>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <id>Dataproces</id>
    </server>
    <server>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <id>Dataproces-snapshot</id>
    </server>
</servers>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <repositories>

            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>https://server/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>Dataproces</id>
                <name>Dataproces-releases</name>
                <url>https://server/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
            </repository>
<!-----------PROBLEM------------>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>Dataproces-snapshot</id>
                <name>Dataproces-snapshot</name>
                <url>https://server/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            </repository>
 <!-----------PROBLEM------------>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>libs-release</name>
                <url>https://server/artifactory/libs-release</url>
            </repository>

        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>https://server02:8439/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots />
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
                <url>https://server02:8439/artifactory/pluginssnapshot</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <properties>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<!-- activeProfiles | List of profiles that are active for all builds. | -->
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

If I outcomment the "Dataproces-snapshot" it installs fine, but when I add the repository maven suddenly wont install, because of the missing pom. The error log :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MinSagSilkeborg Controller 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: https://server02:8439/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/dk/kmd/doc2mail/webservice/1/webservice-1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://server02:8439/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/dk/kmd/doc2mail/jcommander/1/jcommander-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.401 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-06T11:47:03+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/741M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MinSagSilkeborg-Controller: Could not resolve dependencies for project dk.dataproces.MinSagSilkeborg:MinSagSilkeborg-Controller:jar:0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at dk.kmd.doc2mail:webservice:jar:1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for dk.kmd.doc2mail:webservice:jar:1: Could not transfer artifact dk.kmd.doc2mail:webservice:pom:1 from/to Dataproces-snapshot (https://server/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Failed to transfer https://server/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/dk/kmd/doc2mail/webservice/1/webservice-1.pom. Error code 409, Conflict -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

How come maven installs without any problem when the specified repository is outcommented ? 
I know the pom file for the artifact is missing.

Comment: Can you post what your Artifactory log shows when this failure happens? What Artifactory and Maven versions are you using?

Comment: Also, have you tried just using a [Virtual Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) instead of referencing all of you repos?

Comment: It worked putting all into a virtual repository and mirror that.